# Nativescript build error

Tags: ios, angular, mobile, permissions, nativescript

warning: change permissions /Users/sample/Documents/vss/sample/sample/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sample.app/app: Operation not permitted
error: remove /Users/sample/Documents/vss/sample/sample/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sample.app/app/app.component.js: Permission denied
error: couldn't remove '/Users/sample/Documents/vss/sample/sample/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sample.app/app' after command failed: Permission denied

2018-02-05 15:10:36.818 xcodebuild[1943:41205]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-13510/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/Runtime/PBXTargetBuildContext.mm:757
Details:  unexpected successful exit code from cancelled command 
Object:   
Method:   -createCommandInvocationRecordFromInvocation:
Thread:   {number = 2, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

** BUILD FAILED **

Unable to apply changes on device: 3B017AA2-2072-4A26-9533-975000C05BE0. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, there are files/folders that are locked for some reason. You can try deleting them manually.